# Sorting and loops in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This is a program that ask input from the user about the characteristics of a gemstone then prints to the screen. Things like color, price and name. I have written it to an extend where the user enters all this and prints them out. Am now stuck where I should loop and enable the user to enter any number of gemstones. Like if he/she enters 3 gemstones then it should loop and allow the user to enter the characteristics of the 3 gemstone types. I would also like to sort the resulting output of gemstone names in alphabetical order. Appreciated

```
class GemStones
  # input variables
  name = ""
  color = ""
  price = 0
  gemstoneNumber = 0


  # output variable
  gemstoneNumber = 0

  # processing
  print "How many gemstones do you want to enter? "
  gemstoneNumber = gets

  print "What is the name of the gemstone? "
  name = gets

  print "What is the color of the gemstone? "
  color = gets

  print "What is the price of the gemstone? "
  price = gets



  puts " You entered #{gemstoneNumber} The name is #{name}, the color is #{color} and price is
  $ #{price}"



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not wrap the code in `class` in the first place. There is no OOP in your code, hence the class is not needed as well. Also, `gets` returns a string, while for `number` you likely need an integer.

Here would be a [more-or-less] rubyish version of your code:

```
print "How many gemstones do you want to enter? "
#                     ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ get rid of trailing CR/LF
#                           ⇓⇓⇓⇓ convert to integer
gemstoneNumber = gets.chomp.to_i

gemstones =
  1.upto(gemstoneNumber).map do |i|
    puts
    puts "Please enter data for the gemstone ##{i}:"

    print "What is the name of the gemstone? "
    name = gets.chomp # shave the trailing CR/LF off
    print "What is the color of the gemstone? "
    color = gets.chomp
    print "What is the price of the gemstone? "
    price = gets.chomp.to_f # convert to float

    # in Ruby we normally use hashes to store
    #   the named values
    {name: name, color: color, price: price}
  end

puts "You entered #{gemstoneNumber} gemstones. They are:"
gemstones.each do |gemstone|
  puts "Name: #{gemstone[:name]}. " \
       "Color: #{gemstone[:color]}. " \
       "Price: $#{gemstone[:price]}."
end
```

Alternatively, you might use the class instead of hash to store the gemstone info.

---

To sort the gemstones by the name:

```
puts "You entered #{gemstoneNumber} gemstones. They are:"
#         ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE
gemstones.sort_by { |gemstone| gemstone[:name] }.each do |gemstone|
  puts "Name: #{gemstone[:name]}. " \
       "Color: #{gemstone[:color]}. " \
       "Price: $#{gemstone[:price]}."
end
```

---

The good documentation on enumerations might be found in the official ruby docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by (and around.)

Comment: what if I wanted to use a custom module to use in the class. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Normally you define a module with `module Foo; ...; end` and use it by mixing it in with `include`, `prepend` or `extend`.

Comment: What I mean is I would like to create a  module and use it in the class. I made a mistake in the earlier comment. Sorry

Comment: Then my previous comment applies. Create a module and `include` it into the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```
def gem_stones num
  @gem_stones = []
  num.times do |a|
    print "Enter the name of gemstone #{a+1} "
    name=gets.chomp
    print "Enter the color of gemstone #{a+1} "
    color = gets.chomp
    print "Enter the price of gemstone #{a+1} "
    price = gets.chomp.to_f
    @gem_stones.push({name: name, color: color, price: price})
  end
  puts @gem_stones.sort_by {|a| a[:name]}.map{|gem| "Name: #{gem[:name]}, Color: #{gem[:color]}, Price: #{gem[:price]}"}.join("\n")
end

  puts "Ener the number of gem stones you want to enter?"
  num = gets.to_i
  gem_stones num
```